# Acionar botão por tecla de atalho em Java

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma aplicação java criada pelo NetBean IDE 8.0.

Nessa aplicação criei um JFrame e coloquei um JButton, que ao ser pressionado exibe uma mensagem.

```
private void btnExibirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
System.out.println("O botão foi acionado!");
}
```

Como fazer para acionar esse botão através de um atalho pelo teclado (Exemplo: F2)?

Answer (score 7):

A solução que você procura é o [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

*KeyBinding* é o ato de sobrescrever o funcionamento de uma tecla do teclado associando a ela um método a ser executado toda vez que essa tecla for pressionada.

Para aplicar o `KeyBiding` no seu código, coloque o seguinte trecho dentro do construtor da sua classe que estende JFrame:

```
InputMap inputMap = this.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0),"forward");
this.getRootPane().setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, inputMap);
this.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("forward", new AbstractAction(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("F2 foi pressionado");
        btnExibir.doClick();
    }
});
```

No exemplo acima, estou sobrescrevendo o comportamento da sua tecla <kbd>F2</kbd> no linha que diz `inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0),"forward");`.

Para fazer o *KeyBinding* com outras teclas substitua o `VK_F2` pelo código correspondente. Exemplos:

> VK_1: <kbd>1</kbd>
>   VK_A: <kbd>A</kbd>
>   VK_EQUALS: <kbd>=</kbd>

Ou veja [aqui todos os atributos da classe KeyEvent.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Dentro do método `actionPerformed()` você escreve o código que deseja que seja o novo comportamento da tecla.

Para acionar um botão, use o método `doClick()` da sua variável de referência.

Comment: Não compreendi como aplicar sua solução ao meu problema. Pode me dar mais detalhes? Onde codificar essa parte? Juntamente ao arquivo do JFrame? Em que parte?

Comment: @Lucas dentro do seu método main() é chamado algum outro método ou um construtor? Você tem um método que tem uma criação de um `JFrame` dentro ou sua própria classe estende de `JFrame`?

Comment: Minha própria classe estende: `javax.swing.JFrame`

Comment: @Lucas, alterei o exemplo para o caso de uma classe que estende o JFrame, veja se tem alguma dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TeclaAtalho extends JFrame {
    private JButton button;

    public TeclaAtalho() {
        button = new JButton("Click ou aperte F2");

        //ActionListener
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonAction(e);
            }
        });

        //KeyListener para o Frame
        button.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            //Quando soltar a tecla
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                //Se a tecla pressionada for igual a F2
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2) 
                    buttonAction(e);
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        });

        add(button);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //Tanto a tecla de atalho quanto o click no botão
    //vai chamar esse método
    private void buttonAction(AWTEvent e) {
        if (e instanceof KeyEvent) {
            System.out.println("Chegamos aqui a partir da tecla de atalho");
        }

        else if (e instanceof ActionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Chegamos aqui a partir do click no botão (ou a tecla espaço)");
        }
    }

    //Método main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TeclaAtalho();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @Igor, você poderia, além de postar o código, dar uma explicação sobre a solução? Se você considerar que outra pessoa possa passar pelo mesmo problema, possa também usufruir de sua resposta. Qualquer dúvida você pode fazer o [tour] e ainda o tópico [answer] da [help]

Comment: @IgorCostaMelo o código acima  mencionado é um bom exemplo !!