# Chamar método quando a tecla Enter for pressionada

Tags: java, teclado

Como chamar o método de enviar mensagem quando a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> foi pressionada?

**Código**

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    String messageSent = "User: " + writingTextField.getText();
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

        writingTextField.setText("");

        readingTextArea.setText(readingTextArea.getText() + messageSent + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Acionar botão por tecla de atalho em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12594/3117)

Comment: eu ja vi esses sites todos, o problema é que tenho de fazer por o keypressed e não pelo action

Comment: Qual componente você está adicionando keypressed? Não vi problemas no código. Adicione o componente de texto que você quer que o enter funcione.

Comment: tentou verificar que valor possui o e.getKeyCode() ?

Comment: É possível que ele nem deve estar entrando no evento. Talvez o mais apropriado seria colocar o listener no seu TextBox, e não no form.

Comment: o enter nao esta a funcionar sequer. Quando meto no Jtextfield um texto carrego no enter e não funciona, mas com o rato funciona

Comment: Como o @Math disse, o listerner deve ser atribuido ao JtextField. Poste o restante do código pra facilitar a analise.

Comment: ja postei, mas é estranho não dar

Comment: Rodrigo, você está atribuindo o listerner de keypressed ao jbutton, você tem que atribuir ao jtextfield, senão realmente não vai funcionar.

Comment: Consegui! obrigado @Math

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o listener direto no JTextField no momento em que ele é criado.

Abaixo desse código:

```
writingTextField = new JTextField();
```

Crie o listener assim:

```
writingTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            System.out.println("Apertou ENTER");
        }
    }
});
```

Esse código associa um listener para o `writingTextField`, e quando uma tecla for pressionada ele entrará no método em questão. No exemplo acima ele apenas verifica se é um ENTER e imprime uma mensagem informativa.

Se você precisar que seu ENTER seja detectado independente de onde estiver posicionado o seu cursor, veja a solução dessa pergunta: [Acionar botão por tecla de atalho em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12594/3117).

Comment: Resposta correta!